# The SQL relationship between Categories and Sub Categories in Magento

Tags: magento

I have just imported a load of categories into a fresh install of Magento 1.9 using the [Bulk Category Import / Export Extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/bulk-category-import-export.html).

Everything seems to have transferred over correctly, except the sub categories.

This is a rough ASCII diagram of what I am seeing in the Admin Panel under `Catalog > Manage Categories`.

```
[-] [ ] Default Category
     |
    [+] All Products
    [+] Others
     |  Best Sellers
     |  Seasonal Products
```

The catagories all seem to be what I was expecting. There were sub categories in `All Products` and `Others`. But when I click on the `[+]` plus symbol to expand the sub categories, nothing happens and the `[+]` plus symbol disappears.

Ive looked at the SQL in `catalog_category_entities` and all the correct data is there for all the categories.

I expect something isnt matching up in the SQL. I would like to fix this and also learn more about the table structures of Magento.

Can anyone explain to me the relationship between a Category and a Sub Category in SQL so I can fix it, or at the very least have a better understanding of what is going wrong.

Many thanks.

Comment: Hey Jimmery, I don't usually push an extension because I'm more of a do it yourself kinda guy.  But if you want to import categories or products, you can't beat Unirgy.  It's pricey, but it's worth it.   From what I understand, Boris was one of the first developers for Magento and he wrote this extension: https://www.unirgy.com//products/urapidflow/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Categories are connected with the subcategories in the table you have mentioned "**catalog_category_entity**" with the field "**parent_id**", but as I can see from the extension example CSV file, to add these in the CSV, you will have to use the field "**categories**" in a way if for example you are entering the "**Test Category**" with no parents, you just enter "**Test Category**" under "**categories**" field.
If for example you are entering the category named "**Sub Category**" which is child of "**Test Category**", in the field "**categories**" you need to add this: "**Test Category/Sub Category**". Then if you are entering the "**Second Sub Category**" which is child of "**Sub Category**" you go like this: "**Test Category/Sub Category/Second Sub Category**"